# Trying to resolve problem in pandas-python

Tags: python, pandas, plot, solver, programmers-notepad

I have one question. I have point cloud data, and now I have to read and plot the points. If anyone can help me, I would be very thankful. I am using python(pandas, matplotlib,...), and I got all values of X,Y,Z but don't know how to plot all of them to get 3D plot. The values are taken from point cloud data and it has 170 rows and 254 combinations of x,y,z,I,N values.

https://datalore.jetbrains.com/notebook/n9MPhjVrtrIoU1buWmQuDh/MT7MrS1buzmbD7VSDqhGqu/

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('cloud.txt',delimiter='\t')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df1 = df1.apply (pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
#cloud.dropna()
df1.fillna(0,axis=0,inplace=True)
df2=df1.iloc[:,:-1]

df2.head(170)

kolone=[]
i=1
while i<6:
kolone.append(i)
i=i+1
display(kolone)
c=[]
columns=kolone*224
c=c+columns
df2.columns=c
display(df2)

#Reading the points: 1 column is x value, 2 column is y value and 
3 column is z value. 4 and 5 are intensity and noise values and 
they are not important for this.
#First row is exchanged with numerisation of columns: adding 
values 1,2,3,4,5 or x,y,z,I,N values.

x=df2[1]
y=df2[2]
z=df2[3]
r=[]
i=1
while i<225:
r.append(i)
i=i+1
#print(r)
x.columns=r
display(x)
#Reading x coordinates--224 values of x 

i=1
p=[]
while i<225:
p.append(i)
i=i+1
#print(p)
y.columns=p
display(y)
#Reading y coordinates--224 values of y 

i=1
q=[]
while i<225:
q.append(i)
i=i+1
#print(q)
z.columns=q
display(z)
#Reading z coordinates--224 values of z
```

Comment: I'm not going to sign up for a JetBrains account just to look at your code.  You need to include it in your question.

Comment: I updated that, sorry I am new one on this page so don't know how all it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit upsetting that you haven't tried anything at all yet.  The documentation page for matplotlib's 3D scatter plot includes a complete example.

There is no point in going to all that trouble to assign column names.  Indeed, there is really no point in using `pandas` at all for this; you could read the CSV directly into a `numpy` array.  However, assuming you have a dataframe with unnamed columns, it's still pretty easy.

In this code, I create a 50x3 array of random integers, then I pull the columns as lists and pass them to scatter.  You ought to be able to adapt this to your own code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint( 256, size=(50,3))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = df[0].tolist()
y = df[1].tolist()
z = df[2].tolist()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter( x, y, z )
plt.show()
```